# jquerymobile and screen resizing

Tags: jquery-mobile

[I have a page](http://www.cfmzengarden.com/jQueryMobileZenGarden/Table/003.cfm) that is straight from the jQueryMobile site.  I'm including a table of names, but on the iPad, it doesn't allow the user to pinch the screen size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to this answer:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/problem-with-the-zoom-on-ipad

In short, jQuery Mobile injects a fixed viewport size into the page.

Comment: Yeah.  I was able to add $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
      $.mobile.metaViewportContent = "width=device-width";
}); prior to the jQueryMobile.js and it works now.  Thanks!